# Does WebBrowser's DocumentCompleted occurs on the same thread as the one that calls Navigate?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm almost sure it does but I just need to make sure. I don't want my app to be executing another method at the same time DocumentCompleted is being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is raised on the thread that created the WebBrowser, the one that's also pumping the message loop that keeps events on WebBrowser alive.  Calling Navigate() from a worker thread is technically possible but unwise if you want to keep your ducks in a row.

Comment: Hans, is it possible to get a reference to this fact in MS docs?

Comment: my debugger thinks otherwise. see my add

Answer (score -1):

Yes it does (at least, according to the following picture from VS2010 debugger);
[image]

Comment: Meaningless unless you show us that you created webBrowser1 on a thread *other* than the Main Thread and that this thread is an STA and pumps a message loop.  The last thread is clearly doing an Invoke(), whatever a thread buster might be.  Give me my vote back.